# Simple way to make a list of functions with parameters to invoke?

Tags: c#, list, delegates, action

I'm looking for a simple way to create a list of functions with parameters which could be invoked. I almost did it but have some issues with setting the method as one of parameters. 
This is my code:

```
public class PlayerInfo
{
    public static PlayerInfo Instance; // singleton

    public int Energy;
    public int MaxEnergy;
    public List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, cronTab>> cron;

    //some update event for instance every frame of game
    void Update() {
        var keys = cron;
        for (int k=0;k<keys.Count;k++) {
            if (keys[k].Key.CompareTo(System.DateTime.Now) < 0 )
            {
                keys[k].Value.function.Invoke(keys[k].Value.parameter);
                cron.RemoveAt(k);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addEnergy(DateTime date)
    {
        if (PlayerInfo.Instance.Energy < PlayerInfo.Instance.MaxEnergy)
            PlayerInfo.Instance.Energy++;
        date = date.AddSeconds (10);
        PlayerInfo.Instance.cron.Add (new KeyValuePair<DateTime, cronTab>(date, new cronTab(){type = CronType.energy, function = (Action<System.Object>)PlayerInfo.addEnergy, parameter = date}));
    }
}

public class cronTab
{
    public CronType type;
    public System.Object parameter;
    public Action<System.Object> function;
}

public enum CronType
{
    energy,
    mail
}
```

The problem is that `A method or delegate 'PlayerInfo.addEnergy(System.DateTime)' parameters do not match delegate 'System.Action<object>(object)' parameters` and I `Cannot convert method group 'addEnergy' to non-delegate type 'System.Action<object>'.` Do you have any ideas how could I possibly fix it?

Comment: Why do you make `class PlayerInfo` non-`static` and then have `public static PlayerInfo Instance`? Why not just make `PlayerInfo` `static`?

Comment: Because this is only a part of singleton for this function. I need this function non static in order to serialize it properly

Comment: Will every `cronTab.function` take a `DateTime`? If so, you should just make it an `Action<DateTime>` instead, in which case making only that change would make your code compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything becomes way easier when you only use the delegate `Action` here.  Don't have a class that keeps track of the parameter to send, don't try to handle a different number or types of parameters.  Trying to do so is a huge mess that, by necessity, removes all static type safety.

Instead close over whatever parameters you need when creating the delegate to transform the method from whatever it was into an `Action`.

```
public class CronTab
{
    public CronType type;
    public Action action;
}

public static void addEnergy(DateTime date)
{
    if (PlayerInfo.Instance.Energy < PlayerInfo.Instance.MaxEnergy)
        PlayerInfo.Instance.Energy++;
    date = date.AddSeconds(10);
    PlayerInfo.Instance.cron.Add(
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime, CronTab>(
            date,
            new CronTab()
            {
                type = CronType.energy,
                action = () => PlayerInfo.addEnergy(date),
            }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function = ((obj) => PlayerInfo.addEnergy((DateTime)obj))
```

It didn't work before because your `delegate` stated that it takes an `object` but the function you were trying to set it to (`addEnergy`) takes a `DateTime`.

Please note that `System.Object` is equivalent to `object`.

Also, if every `cronTab.function` takes a `DateTime`, then you should make it an `Action<DateTime>`. If you make this change, then you can just have your original code:

```
function = PlayerInfo.addEnergy
```

(Note that you wouldn't need a cast to `Action<DateTime>` here because `PlayerInfo.addEnergy` is already the correct type.)

Comment: This loses all static typing of parameters, still requires methods to have exactly one (not more, no less) parameters, and is way more work than it needs to be.

Comment: Thank u, I didn't make cronTab.function as Action<DateTime> because i'm going to use single list to call methods with different parameters. I'm using System.Object because in Unity there is something like Unity.Object which is colliding with standard one.

Comment: @Servy This doesn't lose static typing, because there wasn't any to begin with. Also, I am assuming that `cronTab.function` functions take exactly one parameter, since that's what was stated in the question. I'm not sure why you would assume otherwise.

Comment: @Jashaszun It's *easier* to code the solution to enable static typing than to do all of this to inhibit it.  The same is true of dealing with any other number of parameters.  It's *easier* to support the general case than to go through all of these hoops and not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler yells at you because your method has incompatible signature than delegate. You either need to change

```
public Action<System.Object> function;
```

to

```
public Action<DateTime> function;
```

or need to change

```
public static void addEnergy(DateTime date)
```

to

```
public static void addEnergy(object date)
```

Then remove the explicit delegate cast in the following line

```
PlayerInfo.Instance.cron.Add (new KeyValuePair<DateTime, cronTab>(date, new cronTab(){type = CronType.energy, function = PlayerInfo.addEnergy, parameter = date}));
```